# Send HTML in SMS (and phone reading it as HTML)

Tags: c#, sms

I am using C# application to send SMS messages to mobile phones. I have a problem with sending links - I can send a link like this:

```
http://example.com/confirmation?id=9423jqismjdj
```

What I would like to do is send SMS like this:

```
<a href='http://example.com/confirmation?id=9423jqismjdj'>confirm</a>
```

so users are not bothered with long links. Problem is, that phones can not read HTML. Is there any way to send HTML to mobile phone as SMS (and phone reading it as HTML)?

Comment: As you already noted, phones cannot understand HTML in SMS messages. I think you answered your own question.

Comment: however if you use a valid URL in the message body, most modern devices automatically convert it to a tappable link anyway, so you don't even need to do this.

Comment: Problem is that link is very long.

Comment: what you might want to do is use a URL-shorterning service so you don't have to put massive URLs into your message. Plenty available online e.g. tinyURL etc.

Comment: If link is longer, device is not converting it to tappable link.

Comment: Like I said, use a shortener. This can also save you money.

Comment: Really good advice, I wasn't aware of something like this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please post this as answer, so I can mark it as solution. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: No problem - done. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted in the question, phones cannot understand HTML placed into SMS messages. SMS is not a web-based platform.

However if you place a valid URL in the message body, most modern devices automatically convert it to a tappable link anyway, so you don't need to worry about this.

A good idea when doing this is to use a URL-shortening service (there are many available online) to save space (and thus money), and avoid any issues with overly-long URLs, and parameter-encoding issues.